# Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: large object 'some_number' does not exist

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, pg, lob

We are exporting and importing data from postgres database using the pg tools from one server instance to another server instance:

eg: Export :

```
pg_dump.exe --file "my_table.sql" --host %connectionHost% --port "5432" --no-owner --username 'myUserName' --no-password --verbose --format=c --blobs --table "table_name" "MyDatabase"
```

eg: Import

```
pg_restore.exe --host "myhost" --port "5432" --username "myUserName" --no-password --dbname "MyDatabase" --data-only --verbose --schema "public" --table "table_name" "my_table.sql"
```

There are no errors either while exporting or importing the data.
But when I try to open the page which has `bytea(Lob)` type column the application fails with the following error message in the log:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to access lob stream; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to access lob stream
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to access lob stream
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.DataHelper.extractString(DataHelper.java:270)
...
 Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: large object 32882 does not exist
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2455)
```

My hibernate Resource is annotated with `@Transactional`
It is working fine when we create the new data in an empty instance, only when we export the data from one instance to another we have this issue.